# What analysis can be performed for categorical and numeric factors and their interactions on numeric response variable?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, ancova, lm, numerics

What analysis can be performed to see the effects of categorical and numeric factors and their interactions on a continuous or numeric response variable? It seems that I need to use ANCOVA, but not sure, some people suggest to use chi squared test. What analysis should I use?

If it is ANCOVA, should the script be like in below in R?

```
mod2 <- lm(ResponseVariable ~ Factor_Categorical + Factor_Numeric + Factor_Categorical*Factor_Numeric, data=Data)
anova(mod2) 
summary(mod2)
```